# Configuring JMS Message Size in WebLogic: weblogic.socket.MaxMessageSizeExceededException

Tags: java, jms, weblogic

I currently have two clients (Producer/Consumer), and I am trying to send a large file via JMS. I am successfully producing and sending the file to the JMS Server without any problems. The problem is when I try to consume the message, and I get the following exception:

```
Aug 24, 2012 11:25:37 AM client.Client$1 onException
SEVERE: Connection to the Server has been lost, will retry in 30 seconds. weblogic.jms.common.LostServerException: java.lang.Exception: weblogic.rjvm.PeerGoneException: ; nested exception is: 
    weblogic.socket.MaxMessageSizeExceededException: Incoming message of size: '10000080' bytes exceeds the configured maximum of: '10000000' bytes for protocol: 't3'
<Aug 24, 2012 11:25:37 AM CDT> <Error> <Socket> <BEA-000403> <IOException occurred on socket: Socket[addr=127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1,port=7001,localport=51764]
 weblogic.socket.MaxMessageSizeExceededException: Incoming message of size: '10000080' bytes exceeds the configured maximum of: '10000000' bytes for protocol: 't3'.
weblogic.socket.MaxMessageSizeExceededException: Incoming message of size: '10000080' bytes exceeds the configured maximum of: '10000000' bytes for protocol: 't3'
    at weblogic.socket.BaseAbstractMuxableSocket.incrementBufferOffset(BaseAbstractMuxableSocket.java:174)
    at weblogic.rjvm.t3.MuxableSocketT3.incrementBufferOffset(MuxableSocketT3.java:351)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readFromSocket(SocketMuxer.java:983)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readReadySocketOnce(SocketMuxer.java:922)
```

I believe this has to do with my MaxMessage size setting in WebLogic and not a code problem (but I could of course be wrong). Here are my settigns for Maximum Message Size
[image: WebLogic settings]

I am not sure why I am getting this exception since the Maximum message size for this protocol is larger than what the exception is claiming... Any thoughts?

I have also tried adding the server start argument -Dweblogic.MaxMessageSize=200000000, but to no avail.
[image]

Here is some code of my where I set the MessageListener, and the message consumer itself.

```
public boolean setClient(MessageListener listener) {

        try {
            Properties parm = new Properties();
            parm.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial",
                    "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
            parm.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", iProps.getURL());
            parm.setProperty("java.naming.security.principal", iProps.getUser());
            parm.setProperty("java.naming.security.credentials",
                    iProps.getPassword());
            ctx = new InitialContext(parm);
            final QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx
                    .lookup(iProps.getConFactory());
            connection = connectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
            ((WLConnection) connection)
                    .setReconnectPolicy(JMSConstants.RECONNECT_POLICY_ALL);
            ((WLConnection) connection).setReconnectBlockingMillis(30000L);
            ((WLConnection) connection).setTotalReconnectPeriodMillis(-1L);
            session = connection.createQueueSession(false,
                    Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup(iProps.getQueue());
            // The following code in the switch statement is the only code that
            // differs for the producer and consumer.
            switch (cType)
                {
                case PRODUCER: {
                    producer = (WLMessageProducer) session
                            .createProducer(queue);
                    // Setting to send large files is done in WebLogic
                    // Administration Console.
                    // Set
                    producer.setSendTimeout(60000L);
                    break;
                }
                case CONSUMER: {
                    consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
                    if (listener != null) {
                        consumer.setMessageListener(listener);
                    }else{
                        log.warning("A Message listener was not set for the consumer, messages will not be acknowledged!");
                    }
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    log.info("The client type " + cType.toString()
                            + " is not currently supported!");
                    return false;
                }

            connection.setExceptionListener(new ExceptionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onException(JMSException arg0) {
                    Logger log2 = new MyLogger().getLogger("BPEL Client");
                    if (arg0 instanceof LostServerException) {
                        log2.severe("Connection to the Server has been lost, will retry in 30 seconds. "
                                + arg0.toString());
                    } else {
                        log2.severe(arg0.toString());
                    }

                }
            });
            shutdownListener = new ShutdownListener(connection, session, producer, consumer);

            connection.start();
            log.info("Successfully connected to " + iProps.getURL());
            return true;
        } catch (JMSException je) {
            log.severe("Could not connect to the WebLogic Server, will retry in 30 seconds. "
                    + je.getMessage());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(30000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                log.warning(e.toString());
            }
            return setClient(listener);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.severe("Could not connect to the WebLogic Server, will retry in 30 seconds. "
                    + e.toString());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(30000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                log.warning(ie.toString());
            }
            return setClient(listener);

        }
    }
```

Here's the MessageListener:

```
public class ConsumerListener implements MessageListener {
    private Logger log;
    private File destination;
    private Execute instructions;

    public ConsumerListener(Execute instructions, File destination) {
        this.instructions = instructions;
        this.destination = destination;
        log = new MyLogger().getLogger("BPEL Client");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message arg0) {

        try {
            if (arg0.getJMSRedelivered()) {
                log.severe("A re-delivered message has been received, and it has been ignored!"
                        + arg0.toString());
            } else {
                try {
                    if (arg0 instanceof TextMessage) {
                        consumeMessage((TextMessage) arg0);

                    } else if (arg0 instanceof BytesMessage) {
                        consumeMessage((BytesMessage) arg0);
                    } else {
                        log.warning("Currently, only TextMessages and BytesMessages are supported!");
                    }
                } catch (JMSException e) {
                    log.severe(e.toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.severe(e.toString());
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    log.severe(t.toString());
                }
            }
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            log.severe(e.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Unwraps the JMS message received and creates a file and a control file if
     * there are instructions present.
     *
     * @param textMessage
     *            JMS message received to be consumed.
     * @throws JMSException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    protected void consumeMessage(TextMessage textMessage) throws JMSException,
            IOException {
        // ***All properties should be lowercase. for example fileName
        // should be
        // filename.***
        String fileName = textMessage.getStringProperty("filename");
        if (fileName == null || fileName.isEmpty()) {
            fileName = textMessage.getStringProperty("fileName");
        }
        if (fileName != null && !fileName.isEmpty()) {
            // Check if the
            // file name is equal to the shutdown file. If it
            // is, shutdown the consumer. This is probably not a good way to
            // do this, as the program can no longer be shutdown locally!

            // We have a file in the queue, need to create the file.
            createFile(destination.getAbsolutePath() + "\\" + fileName,
                    textMessage.getText());
            log.info("Done creating the file");
            String inst = textMessage.getStringProperty("instructions");
            // If there are instructions included, then create the
            // instruction file, and route the message based on this file.
            if (inst != null && !inst.isEmpty()) {
                // We need to rout the file.
                log.info("Instructions found, executing instructions");
                String[] tokens = fileName.split("\\.");
                String instFileName = "default.ctl";
                if (tokens.length == 2) {
                    instFileName = tokens[0] + ".ctl";
                }
                File controlFile = createFile(destination.getAbsolutePath()
                        + "\\" + instFileName, inst);
                Control control = new Control(controlFile);
                instructions.execute(control);
                log.info("Done executing instructions");
            } else {
                log.info("No instructions were found");
            }
            log.info("Done consuming message: " + textMessage.getJMSMessageID());
        }

    }

    /**
     * Unwraps the JMS message received and creates a file and a control file if
     * there are instructions present.
     *
     * @param bytesMessage
     *            The bytes payload of the message.
     * @throws JMSException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    protected void consumeMessage(BytesMessage bytesMessage)
            throws JMSException, IOException {
        // ***All properties should be lowercase. for example fileName
        // should be
        // filename.***
        log.info("CONSUME - 1");
        String fileName = bytesMessage.getStringProperty("filename");
        if (fileName == null || fileName.isEmpty()) {
            fileName = bytesMessage.getStringProperty("fileName");
        }
        if (fileName != null && !fileName.isEmpty()) {
            // Check if the
            // file name is equal to the shutdown file. If it
            // is, shutdown the consumer. This is probably not a good way to
            // do this, as the program can no longer be shutdown locally!

            // We have a file in the queue, need to create the file.
            byte[] payload = new byte[(int) bytesMessage.getBodyLength()];
            bytesMessage.readBytes(payload);
            createFile(destination.getAbsolutePath() + "\\" + fileName, payload);
            log.info("Done creating the file");
            String inst = bytesMessage.getStringProperty("instructions");
            // If there are instructions included, then create the
            // instruction file, and route the message based on this file.
            if (inst != null && !inst.isEmpty()) {
                // We need to rout the file.
                log.info("Instructions found, executing instructions");
                String[] tokens = fileName.split("\\.");
                String instFileName = "default.ctl";
                if (tokens.length == 2) {
                    instFileName = tokens[0] + ".ctl";
                }
                File controlFile = createFile(destination.getAbsolutePath()
                        + "\\" + instFileName, inst);
                Control control = new Control(controlFile);
                instructions.execute(control);
                log.info("Done executing instructions");
            } else {
                log.info("No instructions were found");
            }
            log.info("Done consuming message: "
                    + bytesMessage.getJMSMessageID());
        }

    }

    /**
     * Creates a file with the given filename (this should be an absolute path),
     * and the text that is to be contained within the file.
     *
     * @param fileName
     *            The filename including the absolute path of the file.
     * @param fileText
     *            The text to be contained within the file.
     * @return The newly created file.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    protected File createFile(String fileName, String fileText)
            throws IOException {
        File toCreate = new File(fileName);
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(toCreate, fileText);
        return toCreate;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a file with the given filename (this should be an absolute path),
     * and the text that is to be contained within the file.
     *
     * @param fileName
     *            The filename including the absolute path of the f ile.
     * @param fileBytes
     *            The bytes to be contained within the file.
     * @return The newly created file.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    protected File createFile(String fileName, byte[] fileBytes)
            throws IOException {
        File toCreate = new File(fileName);
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(toCreate, fileBytes);
        return toCreate;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try to change your broadcast type in cluster..if it is already set to UNICAST then please ignore this.

Comment: I've already figured out the problem,  I wasn't setting the           -Dweblogic.MaxMessageSize on the Client applications, it now works fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will also have to increase the Maximum Message Size from the WLS console as shown in the screenshot **for all the managed servers**.

Afterwards perform a restart and the problem will be solved.

Furthermore there is a second alternative solution. According the [Oracle Tuning WebLogic JMS Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/perform/jmstuning.html):

> **Tuning MessageMaximum Limitations**
>
> If the aggregate size of the messages pushed to a consumer is larger than the current protocol's maximum message size (default size is 10 MB and is configured on a per WebLogic Server instance basis using the console and on a per client basis using the  Dweblogic.MaxMessageSize command line property), the message delivery fails.
>
> **Setting Maximum Message Size on a Client**
>
> You may need to configure WebLogic clients in addition to the WebLogic Server instance, when sending and receiving large messages. To set the maximum message size on a client, use the following command line property:
>
> **-Dweblogic.MaxMessageSize**
>
> *Note: This setting applies to all WebLogic Server network packets delivered to the client, not just JMS related packets*.

**EDITED:**

This issue can be resolved by following one or more of the below actions.

> - Configure the System Property -Dweblogic.MaxMessageSize
> - Increase the max message size using the WLS console for the admin and all the managed servers. The steps in the WLS console are: server / Protocols / General
> - Increase the Maximum Message Size from WLS console. The steps in the WLS console are: Queue / Configuration / Threshholds and Quotas / Maximum Message Size

**PROCEDURE** for applying the **weblogic.MaxMessageSize** Property

> Keep a backup of the setDomainEnv files. Stop all the servers. Add the -Dweblogic.MaxMessageSize=yourValue in each setDomainEnv file and more specifically in the EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES line. Afterwards start the ADMIN first and when the ADMIN is in status RUNNING, then start the MANAGED servers.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, though I have already tried both of these, and the problem still persists. What I don't understand is why I can produce a large JMS message and put it on the queue, but I cannot consume the exact same JMS message?

Comment: I have updated the post. Have you tried all the 3 available solutions and none of them resolves your issue? Have you configured the Max Message Size from the WLS console in your Admin Server and all the managed servers? Thanks

Comment: I have tried all 3 options, the only option I am not sure I am doing correctly is the System Property. I edited my question with an image of where I am setting the property. Is this the correct place? I have tried restarting the server after making the changes, but I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: It seems OK. Could you tell me the WLS version?

Comment: WebLogic Server Version: 10.3.5.0

Comment: Which is the configured value for the Protocols/General/Complete message Timeout in the managed servers which host the client that tries to consume the JMS? I can see from the screenshot that it is 480 seconds for the Admin.

Comment: The timeout there is also 480 seconds. I get the error as soon as I start the consumer.

Comment: A last option you could try is to configure the -Dweblogic.MaxMessageSize but NOT from the WLS console. Remove it as startup option from the WLS console and put it in the setDomainEnv files and more specifically in the EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES line. This has to be done for the ADMIN and ALL the managed servers. Afterwards restart the servers. (Keep a backup of the setDomainEnv files before the change.)

Comment: The procedure is the following: Stop all the servers. Add the -Dweblogic.MaxMessageSize in each setDomainEnv file and specifically in the EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES line. Afterwards start the ADMIN first and when the ADMIN is in status RUNNING, then start the MANAGED servers. Keep a backup of the modified files. I hope that this option will work :)

Comment: Tried this multiple times, but I was unsuccessful. I'm thinking it may have something to do with the code since my producer which creates the large message and puts it on the queue works perfectly fine. I am using a `MessageListener` object to consumer messages, would that be a problem? I have added the new code. The exception keeps getting thrown on the `onException` method in the setClient method.

Answer (score 0):

In my case setting the -Dweblogic.MaxMessageSize solved the issue. My questions is what should be the maximum limit of the message size? We just can not keep on increasing the
message size to resolve this issue. Is there any way to optimise this value in addition
with certain other values?

Comment: This would be something you would have to discover yourself by finding the largest message you are sending.

Comment: How do i find the largest t3 message? I do not see any mechanism to log t3 messages in weblogic.

Comment: You can monitor the queue by using the Administration Console, or you can have a more graphical layout using Enterprise Manager, but EM is primarily used for a Live view of the traffic. Another option is just setting the value to the Maximum possible number (This can be found using the administration console when configuring MaxMessageSize on there). If your largest message is over that size, then weblogic won't be able to support it.

Comment: It is actually t3 message in my case and not a JMS Message. I checked the weblogic console and could not find any flag or any configuration which would help me to log or monitor it. Of course by increasing the size it works. But it is more of hit and trial case. I wanted to know how it grows up in proportion to the increase in size of my remote data. Any pointer to any mechanism to log or monitor the t3 message will be very helpful. I asked the same in official weblogic forum but not got any answer yet.